# PhoneGap - Angularjs - Where to store the content?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

Im building an app (android/ios) with Phonegap and Angularjs, I was just wondering how I can store my static data in the app? Do I just create a file where Ill store json or is there another way?

What Id like in the end is for the users to download my app and have direct access to the content without using the internet.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an embedded database like sqlite. You can then decide if it makes sense to ship a prepopulated db with the app or load the data at another time. See the documentation on the [storage api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I saw that in the docs. Is that the only way to ship data along with the app? How do they do it for game apps or heavy content apps?

Comment: In the app my team wrote we stored some things statically and shipped in the db like currency codes and some things we loaded each time the user logged in. Its not the only way but it's probably the best for storing more than just a few properties.